# Can't get a collection using a JPQL query

Tags: jpa, entity, eclipselink, converters, jpql

I have an entity class containing a collection:

```
@Entity(name = "Directory")
@Converters({@Converter(name = "PathConvert", converterClass = PathConvert.class)})
public class Directory {

   @Id
   protected String id;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "Directory_Files", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
   @Convert("PathConvert")
   @Column(name = "file")
   protected Set<Path> files;

}
```

The converter `PathConvert` is necessary because java.nio.file.Path doesn't implement Serializable and therefore can't be directly stored in a column. It simply converts a Path to a String using toString() and a String back to a Path using Paths.get(str).

Now I want to get the set "files" with a JPQL query. Query (executed with Eclipse Link)

```
SELECT u.files FROM Directory u WHERE u.id = :id
```

returns a list of String, but not a list of Path as result. Thus, how can I get a list of Path as result with Eclipse Link? Besides, is it possible to get "files" as a single result?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink should be applying the Converter for this query.  Seems like a bug, please log a bug for the issue.

As a work around you will just need to apply the conversion yourself, or select the whole Directory object and join fetch the files and extract them from the User.

Answer (score 0):

JPA isn't going to be able to coerce a column into an object because it isn't a mapped type.

JPA does have the ability to call a constructor from inside JPQL but I'm not sure that will work in your case since you aren't using a constructor directly.

```
List result = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW example.EmpMenu(e.name, e.department.name) " +
    "FROM Project p JOIN p.employees e " +
    "ORDER BY e.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote the JPA spec, the select clause ought to be

> single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression |
>   aggregate_expression | 
>       identification_variable | OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression

A multi-valued field is none of those. The query is invalid. Correct it.

Comment: Is it really wrong? Eclipse Link prints no exception when the query will be executed. Besides, I also retrieve a set of string with a JPQL query (same structure like the query in the initial question) and there it works without problems.

Comment: I state what is in the JPA spec (public for all to see), hence what is portable. If you really mean, "I'm running this on EclipseLink and what does EclipseLink support" then would be best to ask that (since then it stops being a JPA question)